# Adding images to rtf file in java with iText

Tags: java, image, itext, rtf

I am using itext 2.1.7 to create a rtf file dynamically in a spring MVC controller.
The class I am using is `RTFWriter2`. This works well. But I am not able to add an image to it.

The image is a byte array which I get from a JPA domain object. I also tried to read a sample image from a file. But this does not work either. The image class is from the itext package and its constructor allows an byte array.

This is the code I use:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(user.getStammdaten().getProfileImage());
document.add(img);
document.newPage();
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this scripst will help you.
https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/script-de-clases-rtf-para-jsp-y-php/
Now,
Here there is an example of use:
https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/subiendo-imagenes-png-y-jpg-y-archivos-a-mysql-con-php-y-jsp-y-mostrarlos-en-rtf-usando-clases/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.